# How to generate a unique id for a nested object in MongoDB using Angular-meteor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, meteor, angular-meteor

So, I have the following code in my app.js:

```
Countries = new Mongo.Collection('countries');

// Some skipped code

$scope.addRegion = function(newRegion) {
  $scope.country.regions.push(
    {
      name: newRegion.name,
      createdAt: new Date()
    }
  );
};
```

This successfully adds a new region object in the array and is persistent in the database. Although it has no "_id" field.

How can I generate a unique id for each insertion? (and by unique, I mean unique in the database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `random` package - specifically `Random.id`. From the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/random):

> Returns a unique identifier, such as "Jjwjg6gouWLXhMGKW", that is likely to be unique in the whole world. The optional argument n specifies the length of the identifier in characters and defaults to 17.

Comment: That looks interesting, how do you use it in a function? Adding "_id: Random.id()," before the "name" field doesn't work.

Comment: That looks right. In what way does it not work? Does it throw an error?